# How can one quantify the incremental value of better covariance matrix modeling in portfolio optimization?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, portfolio, covariance, covariance-matrix

Let's say we have two estimators of the covariance matrix, $\hat{C}_1$ and $\hat{C}_2$, and the latter is an improvement on the former.

Is there any measure of the improvement that can be sensibly translated into gains in portfolio performance?

To be more concrete, let $\delta(\hat{C})$ denote a loss function that measures how ``bad'' an estimator $\hat{C}$ is. We know that $\delta(\hat{C}_1) > \delta(\hat{C}_2)$. However, it would be ideal if we can translate the incremental improvement $\delta(\hat{C}_1) - \delta(\hat{C}_2)$ into the expected improvement on some portfolio performance metric, such as the Sharpe ratio.

Comment: Hi: that's going to be very difficult to do because, even if you have a "better" covariance matrix ( you didn't define better ), it's unlikely that this will result in consistently improved returns. Just by random luck, one covariance matrix, A, may result in greater returns than another , B, even when B is a better estimate of the true covariance matrix.

Comment: @markleeds Of course, I'm talking about incremental improvement in expectation.

Comment: Oh okay. Expectation of what ?  returns, sharpe ratio ? if its returns, you could calculate efficient frontiers and compare them. if it's sharpe ratio, you could calculate expected sharpe ratios and compare those.

Comment: @markleeds, "what" is exactly *the* question in this post.

Comment: Mark and Richard - thank you both for the comments. I am trying to see if there is any "standard way" to do what I have in mind. I guess your answers show that there isn't any.

Comment: sharpe ratio is all encompassing because it takes into account return AND sd so I would go for that one. otherwise, you have a greater chance of running into the "I'll pick the stock with the highest return" problem.

Comment: just a heads up that there was a lot of work on covariance matrix shrinkage where people have looked at estimating "better" covariance matrices. ( oliver ledoit comes to mind ). So, maybe look at what they used to see how shrinkage performed.

Comment: An old but well known paper  ( don't remember how useful ) is: "honey. I shrunk the covariance matrix".  Maybe that has some interesting metric for performance.

Comment: the title of the paper above is actually: "Honey, I shrunk the sample covariance matrix". It was well known a long time ago. I don't know what's been done since.